# Add additional column with value of an existing column in Copy Data stage Azure Data Factory (not using SQL)

Tags: dynamics-crm, azure-data-factory, fetchxml

I want to add an additional column to the dataset of the Copy Data stage in Azure Data Factory.

[image]

I am not using a SQL Query as source but a Dynamics 365 fecthxml, which limits the additional column being added in the query.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty certain you can't do this within the Copy data activity. According to the documentation, you can add dynamic and static data, but you can't get to the data being copied.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-overview